# How to open and read a file in Python?

Tags: python, file

All I am trying to do is get Python to open and read a file I have created. I realize there are many other ways to do this, but I'm just wondering why this isn't working. I have my file saved in the same location as this as well. Does python recognize rec for records? I just watched a tutorial on this so I'm rather confused

```
    with open('Broncos.txt') as fo:
        for rec in fo:
           print rec


    Syntax Error:       print rec: <string>, line 6, pos 17
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Does it just not print anything? Does it give you an error message?

Comment: It just gives me and error message @kindall

Comment: And that error message is... ... ... ... ?

Comment: python 2 or python 3?

Comment: im using python 3 @Blorgbeard

Comment: Then try `print(rec)`

Answer (score 1):

I think that error is in the last line of your code. You need to include parenthesis around `rec` in last line of your code:

```
with open('Broncos.txt') as fo:
    for rec in fo:
        print (rec)
```

Comment: From the docs: "**mode** is an **optional** string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. **It defaults to 'r'** which means open for reading in text mode. "

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error you're receiving is most likely due to the lack of parentheses around your print statement (assuming you're using Python 3). A simple change will allow the program to run:

```
with open('Broncos.txt') as fo:
    for rec in fo:
        print(rec)
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Python 2 vs. Python 3: print](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function)
>
> Very trivial, and the change in the print-syntax is probably the most
>   widely known change, but still it is worth mentioning: Python 2’s
>   print statement has been replaced by the print() function, meaning
>   that **we have to wrap the object that we want to print in parantheses**.
>
> Python 2 doesn’t have a problem with additional parantheses, but in
>   contrast, **Python 3 would raise a SyntaxError if we called the print
>   function the Python 2-way without the parentheses**.

So you'd need to do this:

```
with open('Broncos.txt') as fo:
    for rec in fo:
       print(rec)
```